# Suggestion for relevant non-complex simulator

Tags: slam, ros, simulation, simulator, gazebo

I've recently started working on some localization algorithms like *probabilistic road map* and *SLAM* algorithms. What I'm looking for is a software that would help me in simulation for such algorithms. I started with pythons `graphics.py` and have now started working with Gazebo and ROS, but I've found it complex to use.

Is there any similar freeware simulation software that is easy to setup and work with, thus allowing me to reduce my time stressing over the simulation part and working more on the algorithms?

Comment: Check out the wiki page for [simulator](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/simulator/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use matlab or and python with a set of fixed features in space represented as points. Don't do any vision processing. At this point any vision processing would be overkill.

you are making this way too complex.

the measurements for your slam can be angles to features. create a set of 30 features randomly populating a 20m by 20m square. make your view point move in a circle around the square.

this is enough to get started with slam.

if you only rely on other people's packages and modules without going through the trouble of building your own you will never really get a sense of how these things work and break.

Comment: could you specify which python package would be most useful.

Comment: you would need numpy for some math

Comment: I guess I'll start with the turtle package in python then

Answer (score 0):

[ZeroSim](https://github.com/fsstudio-team/ZeroSimROSUnity) is built with Unity.  It's not necessarily "easy" but arguably easier then Gazebo.  Definitely creating and iterating environments in [ZeroSim](https://github.com/fsstudio-team/ZeroSimROSUnity) is much easier then Gazebo.

Disclosure:  I am a [ZeroSim](https://github.com/fsstudio-team/ZeroSimROSUnity) developer.